# Showing $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left({1 \over \sqrt n} + {(-1)^{n-1}\over n}\right)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, divergent-series

> Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}a_n$ diverges, where $\displaystyle a_n = {1 \over \sqrt n} + {(-1)^{n-1}\over n}$.

I just have a simple question in regards to divergence of a series. Here's what I did so far:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}a_n & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[{(-1)^{n+1} \over \sqrt n} + {1 \over n}\right] \\ &=\underset{\text{converges by AST}}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^{n+1} \over \sqrt n}} + \underset{\text{diverges}}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1 \over n}} \end{align}$$

**My question**: Does it suffice to say that if one series diverges and another converges, that the entire series will diverge? Obviously we can't immediately invoke the AST at the beginning because the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is not nonincreasing, so my thought was to do some algebra to show that the sequence can be broken into both a convergent and divergent series.

Comment: My bad, it shows that that the original sum cannot be absolutely convergent.

Comment: Note that conditionally convergent series can be made to diverge themselves.

Comment: @SimpleArt, this is a good observation. However, the theorem supporting such reasoning is not presented until a later section in my textbook, meaning I don't have the tools of absolute and conditional convergence just yet.

Comment: You change $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ to $\frac{1}{n}$ at one point up there.

Comment: The definition of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges is that the sequence $A(k) = \sum_{n=1}^k a_n$ converges. Here you have $A(k) = B(k)+C(k)$ where $B(k) = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $C(k) = \sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{k}$. As you said $B(k)$ converges and $C(k)$ diverges, therefore $A(k)$ diverges

Comment: @user361424, thanks for catching that. This was a $\LaTeX$ error on my part.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes that's why I tried to make it clear that it follows from the definition of the convergence of the sum of two sequences

Comment: @SimpleArt no I won't

Comment: "Does it suffice to say that if one series diverges and another converges, that the entire series will diverge?" Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if one converges and the other diverges, the sum diverges. If the sum converged, then the difference between the sum and the convergent term would converge, but this difference is the divergent term.